# Printing variable in the server code

Tags: apache, perl, server

I have inherited some code that is written in Perl and makes HTTP requests between the server and the client. I want to print few variables that is in the server code but that raises errors when I use the print statement. The variables are scalars, arrays or hashes. I want to print the output to the terminal and only for debugging purposes. Few errors I get are-

```
malformed header from script 'get_config': Bad header: self=$VAR1 = bless( {

Response header name 'self=Bio' contains invalid characters, aborting request
```

A simple `print 'test'` raises error like

```
malformed header from script 'get_config': Bad header: test
```

How do I print the variable values without any errors?

Comment: This is not a Perl question. HTTP responses need to indicate content type. See [Content-Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Standard_response_fields). For debugging purposes, use [CGI::Carp](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Carp).

Answer (score 7):

You haven't explained yourself very well at all. But, from the errors you're getting, I assume this is a CGI program.

A CGI program sends its output to `STDOUT`, where the web server catches it and processes it in various ways. In order for this to work, the data that your program prints to `STDOUT` needs to follow various rules. Probably the most important of those rules is that the first output from your program must be the CGI headers - and at the least, those headers should include a `Content-type:` header.

I assume that you're trying to display your debugging output before your program has sent the CGI headers. That's not going to work.

But do you really want to send your debugging output to `STDOUT`? That seems like a bad idea. If you use `warn()` instead of `print()` then your output will go to `STDERR` instead - and in most web servers, `STDERR` is connected to the web server's error log.

For more control over the output generated by `warn()`, see the [CGI::Carp](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Carp) module.